# How to reconstruct type and data structure in disassembled C/C++ program?

Tags: assembly, binary, types, reverse-engineering, disassembly

I have made a binary executable file disassembled using disassembler like IDA Pro. Now, I plan to recognize type and data structure information as much as possible. Is there any resource reference or ideas to help me finish the task?

Thank you!~

**EDIT**:

Thanks very much for tips below. Besides `type and data structure information`, any ideas about `class object recognition`?

Comment: You have a hamburger. Can you figure out if the cow was brown or black and white?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The already mentioned [Reversing: Secrets of Reverse engineering](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764574817) by Eldad Eilam has some nice descriptions of how various control flow and data structures look in the assembly. However, since you specifically mention classes, I would like to plug [my article](http://www.openrce.org/articles/full_view/23) on Visual C++ implementation. A lot of it applies to other compilers as well.

BTW, I would recommend starting with small functions/classes and identifying them in the binary. If you are using Visual C++ and compile your code with debug info (Debug build or /Zi on command line), IDA (at least recent versions) will detect and offer to load the PDB symbols. That will make identification of your code easier.

Comment: Thank you, Igor. I've heard of you as a great reverse engineer. :) Thanks for tips and articles.

Answer (score 1):

This is practically impossible; adequate information simply *does not exist* in the file after compilation.

You need to walk through the disassembly by hand at run-time and try to decipher the numbers yourself.

Comment: @Mehrdad Hi, Mehrdad. I dont think so. As my question says, i just want as much information as possible not completely. And there are some great decompilation tools based the disassembled file to do the work, but not open source. I can only refer to some papers focus on this point.

Comment: @Jason: The *only* type information you can recover from a compiled executable would come from RTTI and the executable's export tables, both of which can very well not exist, and both of which are incomplete. Debugging symbols would be of tremendous help, but they don't usually exist for release builds, so you probably won't find them helpful either. As such, there's no real way for you to recover most executables; only a few specially-built executables can have type information extracted from them.

Comment: @Mehrdad: That's simply not true. It doesn't happen automatically, but you can recover quite a bit more if you're willing to put some work into it.

Comment: @Jerry: Really? Would you mind decompiling `C:\Windows\Notepad.exe` and posting the code somewhere then (without using debug symbols)? I'd love to see it.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yes, I would mind. If, however, you have a patent and want to know whether somebody infringes it, I'll be happy to disassemble target products to determine similarity to your patent claims (for an appropriate price, of course). There's also a *huge* difference between "recognize type and data structure information", and "decompile".

Comment: @Jerry: Of course, there's a difference. But unless you know what the data types represent -- which basically means having some external information about the executable, like having knowledge about what external functions they're calling -- it's darn hard to read a bunch of `mov eax, ebx` instructions and figure out what they do. (If one of them points to a user-readable string, though, that's a different story.) It's possible to *some* degree but the result is in rarely adequate for most purposes.

Comment: @Mehrdad: For what purpose(s) is it inadequate? Yes, it's hard work, but a long ways from impossible.

Comment: Well, gentlemen, (really) hard work when discussing assembly doesn't surprise me. But if it is possible, we always can try to automatize the task. I would like a program that do that for me.

Comment: @Jerry: For figuring out what an arbitrary function does, for example, when you have no idea whether it's inlined (and so whether you're indeed working on a different function) or what calling convention it's using.

Comment: @Dr Beco: I think you should like [our decompiler](http://hex-rays.com/decompiler.shtml) then :)
@Mehrdad: have a look at [this](http://pastebin.com/Xn73NDvU). It's automatic decompilation without any manual work.

Comment: @Igor: Are you *sure* the program did not use external knowledge of the headers of `WinMain`, `GetCommandLineW`, `GetSystemMetrics`, `GetCurrentProcessId`, `SetWinEventHook`, `GetMessageW`, etc., and `GetProcAddress` as well as the calling conventions in order to decompile this?

Comment: @Igor: By the way, *how in the world* did your decompiler get the name of `HWINEVENTHOOK` and `FARPROC` from `Notepad.exe`?

Comment: Of course the decompiler assumes the standard calling conventions (which you can override manually), how else would you accomplish anything? The names and types come from the parameters to the well-known Win32 API calls and are tracked upwards in the call tree. See description of PIT [here](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/technologies.htm). No actual debugging info was used, only the code and names of imported functions in the PE file.

Comment: @Igor: My entire point was that this *depends* on outside knowledge of the well-documented OS API. But if you're trying to decompile a function that doesn't call any outside procedures (which isn't exactly uncommon either), it's pretty darn hard to accomplish anything.

Comment: We live in a real world, with real apps. Even if the function doesn't call anything, it gets its input from the caller, and there should be some information available there. Anyway, you asked for a notepad decompilation, you got it :)

Comment: While we're at it... I found [just the function](http://pastebin.com/9vzSk7YM) you describe. I listed the original assembly, the default decompilation, and then I changed types of some variables manually, since it looked plausible that the function works with wide char strings. Going up you, could see that its result was used in a call to MessageBoxW.

Comment: @Igor: (1) But how do you understand the behavior a function that's 10 calls deep, if you only have knowledge of the 1st-level function? That's pretty darn hard without outside info. (2) I'm not sure which function you're referring to... are you referring to me or someone else?

Comment: @Mehrdad: yes, sorry, I meant the "function that doesn't call any outside procedures". And of course you can have them nested, but that just means you have more information about what's done to the parameters passed from top to bottom :) You may not be able to figure out some rarely-used fields, but you definitely can recover most of the info if you keep at it. It's like a crossword puzzle - first you get the easy words, then as you see more and more letters you can fill in the harder ones.

Comment: @Igor: But how do you recover the *names* of the variables and parameters? That's the problem here! Unless you already know what the function is supposed to do (like `WinMain`), there's no way to figure that out, which makes it immensely harder to figure out what the code is doing.

Comment: Who said anything about recovering names? Naturally, you would never guess that someone called his loop counter IReallyLikeLongNames unless you have debug info, but names are much less important than actual types. And for the types you can have if not 100% certainty then pretty good guesses in most cases.

Comment: @Igor: Well in that case, perhaps I misunderstood the question, but to me, names were always an integral part of type information (I imagined *type information* to be a superset of *type layout*, and that it would include names)). If you don't need strings and can work with pure numbers then I guess it's not quite as hard to get the information (although the info won't be quite as handy either).

Comment: @Igor is that your voice in the video? :D Nice decompiler. @Mehrdad, ah... variables names are not part of the striped assembly... :( But do not worry, most programmers chose poorly its names anyway! :D

Answer (score 1):

Based on the type of access instructions do in some part of the memory, one can guess and chose some kinds of basic types like boolean, integer, floating points, even some string messages (easy if it is ascii char, but nowadays we see utf also).

Even if you do chose one or another to "represent" what you think it is in the memory, there is no relation between your options and the real code.

Places you should look to have a clue are the push instructions before each call to a function, as they are likely to be parameters. If you know the original language, you get some information on the [calling convention used](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions).

But, as Mehrdad said, there is simple no adequate information you can trust.

Take care,
Beco

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of books you might find useful:

1. Reverse Engineering Code with IDA Pro
2. Reversing: Secrets of Reverse engineering
3. The IDA Pro book

Along with that, it's handy to have an API reference and an "internals" book on whatever OS you're dealing with. You can figure out quite a bit based on what's passed to which API functions.

Comment: First book is really not recommended. It's a random collection of badly edited text. It was handled so badly by the publisher that one of the _authors_ made a one-star review at Amazon. The other two are very good though.

Answer (score 1):

There have been some recent research papers on this topic, they are probably open-source and might even have web interfaces by which you can submit your binary for analysis, though they probably handle Elf binaries only. They have achieved fairly impressive results:

Digging for Data Structures
by Anthony Cozzie, Frank Stratton, Hui Xue, and Samuel T. King

Automatic Reverse Engineering of Data STructures from Binary Execution
by Zhiqiang Lin, Xiangyu Zhang, and Dongyan Xu